# How can Jenkins pipeline work with monorepo

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Am very new to Jenkins. My repository is a monorepo - contains two sub projects, `web_app` and `native_app`. I want to use Jenkins as CI engine so that every time code pushes to the repo Jenkins will help do the build-test-delivery workflow automatically.

I created a pipeline project, intuitively seems I should create two `Jenkinsfile`, each under related folder, i.e.:

```
web_app/
  |-Jenkinsfile
native_app/
  |-Jenkinsfile
```

However, I soon realized this will result in problems - I need to change working directory for nearly every stage/step. Tried

```
stage('Build') { 
  steps {
      sh 'cd ./web_app/'
      sh 'ls'
      sh 'git pull'
    }
}
```

but doesn't work, the working directory is not changed.

I haven't found an effective method to change workspace for entire pipeline, and am worried that this monorepo structure would result in more problem with Jenkins in the future. Should I split this repository, or is there some handy way to change work directory?

Comment: Sounds like you may be looking for [JENKINS-43749](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43749).

Comment: @mkobit and that's still `unresolved`.. guess I should just split repos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `dir` step to change the directory of a block of steps. Your sample code would look like this:

```
stage('Build') {
  dir('web_app') {
    sh 'ls'
    sh 'git pull'
  }
}
```

[Documentation of the `dir` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-dir-code-change-current-directory)

> dir: Change current directory
>
> Change current directory. Any step inside the dir block will use this directory as current and any relative path will use it as base path.
>   path
>
> Type: String